# Grouping Solr results in Solr 3.6.1 API causes NullPointerException when parsing result

Tags: java, solr

As long as I limit my query to:

```
SolrQuery solrQuery = new SolrQuery();

solrQuery.set("q", query); //where query is solr query string (e.g. *:*)
solrQuery.set("start", 0);
solrQuery.set("rows", 10);
```

everything works fine - results are returned and so on.

Things are getting worse when I try to group results by my field "Token_group" to avoid duplicates:

```
SolrQuery solrQuery = new SolrQuery();

solrQuery.set("q", query); //where query is solr query string (e.g. *:*)
solrQuery.set("start", 0);
solrQuery.set("rows", 10);

solrQuery.set("group", true);
solrQuery.set("group.field", "token_group");
solrQuery.set("group.ngroups", true);
solrQuery.set("group.limit", 20);
```

Using this results in `HttpSolrServer` no exceptions are being thrown, but trying to access results ends up in NPE.

My querying Solr method:

```
public SolrDocumentList query(SolrQuery query) throws SolrServerException {

    QueryResponse response = this.solr.query(query); //(this.solr is handle to HttpSolrSelver)
    SolrDocumentList list = response.getResults();

    return list;

}
```

note that similar grouping (using the very same field) is made in our other apps (PHP) and works fine, so this is not a schema issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved my issue. In case someone needs this in future:

When you perform a group query, you should use different methods to get and parse results. 
While in ungrouped queries

```
QueryResponse response = this.solr.query(query); //(this.solr is handle to HttpSolrSelver)
SolrDocumentList list = response.getResults();
```

will work, when you want to query for groups, it won't.

**So, how do I make and parse query?**

Below code for building query is perfectly fine:

```
SolrQuery solrQuery = new SolrQuery();

solrQuery.set("q", query); //where query is solr query string (e.g. *:*)
solrQuery.set("start", 0);
solrQuery.set("rows", 10);

solrQuery.set("group", true);
solrQuery.set("group.field", "token_group");
solrQuery.set("group.ngroups", true);
solrQuery.set("group.limit", 20);
```

where last four lines define that `Solr` should group results and parameters of grouping. In this case `group.limit` will define how many maximum results within a group you want, and `rows` will tell how many max results should be there.

Making grouped query looks like this:

```
List<GroupCommand> groupCommands = this.solr.query(query).getGroupResponse().getValues();
```

referring to **[documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/3_6_0/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/response/GroupCommand.html)**, GroupCommand contains info about grouping as well as list of results, divided by groups.

**Okay, I want to get to the results. How to do it?**

Well, in my example there's only one position in `List<GroupCommand> groupCommands`, so to get list of found groups within it:

```
GroupCommand groupCommand = groupCommands.get(0);

List<Group> groups = groupCommand.getValues();
```

This will result in list of groups. Each group contains its own `SolrDocumentList`. To get it:

```
for(Group g : groups){
    SolrDocumentList groupList = g.getResult();
    (...)
}
```

Having this, well just proceed with `SolrDocumentList` for each group.

**I used grouping query to get list of distinct results. How to do it?**

This was exacly my case. It seems easy but there's a tricky part that can catch you if you're refactoring already running code that uses `getNumFound()` from `SolrDocumentList`.

Just analyze my code:

```
/**
 * Gets distinct resultlist from grouped query
 * 
 * @param query
 * @return results list
 * @throws SolrServerException 
 */
public SolrDocumentList queryGrouped(SolrQuery query) throws SolrServerException {


    List<GroupCommand> groupCommands = this.solr.query(query).getGroupResponse().getValues();

    GroupCommand groupCommand = groupCommands.get(0);

    List<Group> groups = groupCommand.getValues();

    SolrDocumentList list = new SolrDocumentList();

    if(groups.size() > 0){

        long totalNumFound = groupCommand.getNGroups();

        int iteratorLimit = 1;

        for(Group g : groups){
            SolrDocumentList groupList = g.getResult();

            list.add(groupList.get(0));   

            //I wanted to limit list to 10 records    
            if(iteratorLimit++ > 10){
                break;
            }
        }

        list.setNumFound(totalNumFound);


    }

    return list;

}
```